# Alexa Skill Flow Builder - how to dynamically update player count

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, alexa-presentation-language

How do I player a player count in Alexa skill flow Builder?

1. Select a number of players. and then
2. Flow Builder updates with the number of players to
3. Ask each player a question in the game.

where should I start going? is there a way for me to scale experience across multiple players based off of a slot?
can I change the flow of the experience dynamically based off of the number of players I received from a slot?

Answer (score 0):

Of course! We have an amazing tool: the dialog.directives. You can manually trigger intents in your handlers. You can also fill the slots for the user (in case you need to). You need to simply trigger that intent n number of times, where n is the number of players you have.

You can achieve that by following different paths. Give it a try and let me know if you need any more help :)

Read more: https://developer.amazon.com/es-mx/docs/custom-skills/dialog-interface-reference.html#scenario-delegate